# How to remove hasbang from url in vue js

Tags: vue.js

I want to remove hashbang from url in vue js
 i am trying
 mode:'history',
  hashbang:false,
  history:true,
  linkActiveClass: "active",
but still getting hash in url

Comment: `mode: "history"` should work.

Comment: Changing it to `<a href="/relativepath">Click</a>` or use [router-link](https://router.vuejs.org/en/api/router-link.html) components should work properly.

Comment: It's difficult to know what's wrong without seeing your code. Please complete your question with some code sample, the vuejs and vue router configuration,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When initialising your Vue router, this is the bare minimum code to make it work:

```
const router = new Router({
  mode: 'history'
})
```

You'd then need to pass the router instance (`router` here) to your Vue instance on creation:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: { App },
  template: `<App/>`,
  router
})
```

With just this setup, `vue-router` should already work in [history mode](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#html5-history-mode). However, most likely you'll also want to add routes to your router instance:

```
const router = new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [...]
})
```

If you could share some code, then it would go a long way in letting us help you further.

For now, you can also check a small [router example](https://codesandbox.io/s/o4nyx5vj4q) (notice how the route in the browser URL changes to `/foo` and then to `/bar`, without a hash).

Comment: Great to hear! Glad to be of help

Answer (score 1):

if you're using `Vue v3` and `vue-router v4` this line in router.js helped me to remove the hashtag from the url:

```js
const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(process.env.BASE_URL),
  routes
})
```

Answer (score 0):

For those using Quasar Framework `hash` can be remove by going to `quasar.conf.js`

search for `build` property then set `vueRouterMode: 'history'`